# Laravel 5.2 Get records the same ordering as in whereIn()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have this array with record IDs:

```
$record_ids = [60, 66, 70, 64, 69, 67, 65, 57];
```

And I get rows by using model, like this:

```
$result = Model::whereIn('id', $record_ids)->get();
```

The problem - I want to get rows the same order as in my $record_ids array. Laravel returns me these rows in ascending ID order like this:

```
[57, 60, 64, 65, 66, 67, 69, 70]
```

How to do that? How to make Laravel "Not to order by ID ASC by default"? Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `orderByRaw()` like as

```
$result = Model::whereIn('id', $record_ids)
          ->orderByRaw("field(id,".implode(',',$record_ids).")")
          ->get();
```

Comment: Do you have a Postgres compatible version?

Answer (score 4):

use the sortBy method in the collection, you can order by an array of ids.

```
$theIds = [2,76,423];

$collection = $collection->sortby(function($model) use ($theIds){
   return array_search($model->id, $theIds);
});
```

it would probally be best to slice the $record_ids this would act as a offset and limit then sort the returned collection once the query has been run.

Comment: This is underrated answer. OrderByRaw may be problematic with RDBMS's like PostgreSQL and introduce security risks with SQL injections. This should be rather handled in Laravel, not in DB, like you propose.

Comment: Nice one! Just what I was looking for